# jquery-ui datepicker theme not shown properly

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker, jquery-ui-theme

I tried adding a jquery-ui datepicker to my website. I downloaded the necessary jquery-ui js components and Smoothness theme css. The problem is that when I add the widget to my site, it looks like this:

[Broken datepicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WS5ar.png)

as opposed to this:

[What it should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOTOG.png)

I'm using customized twitter bootstrap as the main style for my site, but it doesn't seem to affect the styling of the widget according to Chrome Inspect element.

Any ideas what could be wrong, or how could I investigate this further?

Comment: if you use bootstrap css you have to user  http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-datepicker/

Comment: I dislike the notion that I **have** to use it, but thanks, I'll look into that, it looks good.

Answer (score 0):

you need to change the size of your font :

```
.ui-widget {
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

Comment: That's not it, it just makes the font size smaller (duh!). The issue is with the date boxes (<td>-elements with the day numbers in them) being of non-uniform size. Also the month selectors are all wrong. Changing the font size just makes the whole widget smaller.